# TinyMCE breaking if mso clause

Tags: html, tinymce

Struggling with this behaviour from Tiny MCE:

Just hit the source code and paste the HTML code and every single line with:

```
<!--[if mso | IE]>
```

Is converted to:

```
<!-- [if mso | IE]>
```

Tiny just adds the white space after -- that breaks my code.
Tried with different versions, even with the demo version available in their website.

My init has everything disabled:

```
convert_fonts_to_spans : false,
force_hex_style_colors : false,
fix_table_elements : false,
fix_list_elements : false,
fix_nesting : false,
forced_root_block : false,
validate_children : false,
remove_linebreaks : false,
force_p_newlines : false,
force_br_newlines : false,
remove_redundant_brs : false,
convert_newlines_to_brs : false,
apply_source_formatting : false,
remove_trailing_nbsp : false,
remove_script_host : false,
convert_urls : false,
paste_as_text: true,
remove_script_host : false,
cleanup : false,
cleanup_on_startup : false,
verify_html : false,
```

But noting stops Tiny.

Disable every option and nothing resulted.

Answer (score 0):

Just handle it after SUBMIT (server-side or javascript)